# How to connect Mule 4.1.x with AWS Athena Database

Tags: connection, mule

scenario 1. I used third party connector like cdata(cdata-amazonathena-connector-18.0.6817-mule-plugin.jar) it works fine with limited features. But to avail complete features using JDBC Connector(AthenaJDBC42_2.0.5.jar) so added in build path as a external jar application get builds but not deploying.

scenario 2. Created generic connector and imported AthenaJDBC42_2.0.5.jar and added required dependency entry in pom, but driver class not loading while build the application.

Can you please suggest how achieve athena connections in mule 4.1.x.

Thanks in advance. 
Chandra

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 2 is the correct one. You should not use Studio's add to build path feature with Maven based projects. All Studio 7/Mule 4 projects are Maven based.
The issue is probably related to have to having to configure the JDBC driver as a shared library. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/db/db-configure-connection#setting-the-jdbc-driver for instructions.
Use the latest version of Anypoint Studio to create the project to avoid running into issues of previous version sharing packages. Studio 7.3 was recently released so I recommend to use that version as a minimum.